# Symfony2 fetch data from table with OneToOne relationships

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I got problem when I want to fetch data from the table that have OneToOne relationships. Here I have table `tbl_user`and I make a relationship to a table named `tbl_admin`.

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace Eifl\MainBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id",type="string")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Eifl\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin", mappedBy="userAdmin", cascade="remove")
     */
    public $userAdminType;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**Admin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Eifl\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Admin
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_admin")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Eifl\AdminBundle\Entity\AdminRepository")
 */
Class Admin
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Eifl\MainBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userAdminType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_Admin", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    public $userAdmin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    public $position;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserAdmin()
    {
        return $this->userAdmin;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userAdmin
     * @return string
     */
    public function setUserAdmin($userAdmin)
    {
        $this->userAdmin = $userAdmin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $position
     * @return string
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Now, in my `controller.php`, when I fetch data from `admin` with this code:

```
$admin = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EiflAdminBundle:Admin')->findOneBy(array('userAdmin'=>'MyIdUser'));

$username= $admin->getUserAdmin()->getUsername();
```

I can use the function `getUserAdmin()` to fetch some function that I declared in class `user` such as function `getUsername()` to get the username or function `getId()` to get the user id. But the code above only fetch one record. I want to fetch multiple record from table `admin`, so I change the code above into these code:

```
$admin = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EiflAdminBundle:Admin')->findAll();

$username= $admin->getUserAdmin()->getUsername();
```

And I got the problem. The error shows:

```
Error: Call to a member function getUserAdmin() on a non-object in ...
```

I can't use the function `getUserAdmin()` to call another function in class `User`.
How can I fix this problem?

Note: the function of class `user` extends from FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` returns an array. For example this will work:

```
$admins = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EiflAdminBundle:Admin')->findAll();

$usernames = array();
foreach ($admins as $admin) {
    $usernames[] = $admin->getUserAdmin()->getUsername();
}
```